# Simplify a multidimensional array to a string

Tags: php, arrays

I have this kind of array in my `$tag` variable.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [tag_name] => tag-1
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [tag_name] => tag-2
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [tag_name] => tag-3
        )
)
```

What I'm trying to do is get all the tag names and implode them with a coma then make it a value for a text input field.

I've tried for and foreach loops so many different ways but with not much success. I'm using CodeIgniter if that helps.

Comment: `<?php $imploded_data = '';foreach($original_array as $arr){$imploded_data = $imploded_data.','.$arr['tag_name'];} echo trim(',',$imploded_data);`

Comment: `implode(',', array_column($tag, 'tag_name'));;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) followed by `join` or `implode`

Try this :

```
$string = join(',', array_column($array, 'tag_name'));
```

**Explanation:**

`array_column` returns the values from a single column from the input array

For your array, `array_column($array 'tag_name')` returns an array containing values of index `tag_name`, i.e returned array would be :

```
Array
(
    [0] => tag-1
    [1] => tag-2
    [2] => tag-3
)
```

Joining with `join` or `implode` , you get your desired string,

```
//$string = "tag-1,tag-2,tag-3"
```

Comment: Gald to have helped :)

Comment: @RobinPanta Can you add some explanation? StackOverflow is useless if people just copy code snippets and learn nothing :P so at least let the asker or other people who visit the question know how this answer works...

Comment: @YotamSalmon Edited :) happy? :P

Comment: @RobinPanta Tbh, Yeah :D Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

A simple and obvious solution might be:

```
$res = "";
for ($i = 0; $i < count($tag); $i++) {
    $res .= $tag[$i]["tag_name"] . ",";
}
$res = trim($res, ","); //Removing the extra commas
echo $res;
```

You basically iterate through the array, and every element you iterate through, you add it's `tag_name` to a `$res` string.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

```
$tag = implode(', ', array_column($array, 'tag_name'));
```

Using [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$tag = implode(', ', array_map(function ($tag) {
          return $tag['tag_name'];
        }, $array));
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple one liner !!

```
$array = [
    [
        "tag_name" => 'tag-1'
    ],
    [
        "tag_name" => 'tag-2'
    ],
    [
        "tag_name" => 'tag-3'
    ],
];

implode(',', array_column($array, 'tag_name'));
```